# Can't use my 9.0.1 iPhone with Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift

My Macbook and my iPhone are updated to the OS X 10.11 Capitan and iOS 9.0.1, but when I try to use my iPhone as a running device with Xcode, it tells me I can't use it because of the version of them.

I can't upgrade xCode (6.1). On the App Store, it tells me I'm on the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Current iOS is 9.0.2
Latest Xcode release is 7.0.1 - from the [App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12)
I'd try updating to those first.

If iTunes doesn't seem to think it needs updating, you could always get the .ipsw file from one of the many direct download links available [the files come directly from Apple, just the links are published separately] then hold  <kbd>Alt ⌥</kbd>  whilst clicking the "Check for Update" button in iTunes & manually navigate to the .ipsw

One source of links is always Redmondpie - http://www.redmondpie.com/download-ios-9.0.2-links-for-iphone-ipad-ipod-touch-ipsw/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My bad, my iPhone is on 9.0.2. I can't upgrade xcode from the AppStore. I'm trying to install the new xcode 7 with the .dmg file.

Comment: I'm not much of an Xcode user, so not certain, but I thought you just trashed the Xcode 6 app & then DL Xcode 7. Might be that major version numbers aren't directly upgradeable.